# Posting in wordpress database as a new post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two php websites, I have a form in one custom page which simply inserts data in one database ....all I want is to insert this same data in my second site which is wordpress..to be inserted as a new post.

Ex: in the form i fill title, date, etc in my 1st databse which is a simple php site, now i want is same post gets inserted in my wordpress databse...title as title and data as date.

Don't want to use XML etc..as i have both database under same hosting so i have access to both database with single php form...all i want to know is dependent tables for wordpress entry but with an example :)

Thanks
Luckyy

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WordPress`'s functionality outside of `WordPress`, just create a subfolder in your site's root directory, i.e. `http://yoursite.com/blog` and upload `WordPress` in your `blog` sub-folder. For more [read this on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website).

Then, in order to transform regular `PHP` pages into ones that utilize WordPress, you need to add either of the following code snippets to the start of each page.

```
<?php 
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require('./wp-blog-header.php');
    // rest of the code using power of wordpress
?>
```

Now look at the [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) function on `Codex` to know that how you can insert post into `WordPress` pragmatically, Also [another simplified article](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/02/09/programmatically-creating-posts-in-wordpress/) if it helps. Now, you know how to use `WordPress`'s functions/functionality out side of `wordpress` and also you know how you can use `wp_insert_post`, now just setup a `PHP` page with a form and submit the form using `POST` methos and the prepare the data for the post to be inserted into the `WordPress` database (validate inputs) and finally insert using `wp_insert_post` function. Please [read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) on codex for more information.

Comment: No sheikh, they are two different sites on two domains hosted under same hosting...don't want to integrate wordpress in other site...just want to insert a post that will appear as a new post in wordpress site as i hav the database access of wordpress too from other site.

Comment: If you have access to wp_load (as you seem to as described above), sheik's answer is the best way to go about doing this. The vast majority of the time it's best to use the API provided by the software than to edit its database directly, for forward-compatibility. Why reinvent the wheel? You don't need to integrate Wordpress into the entire second site, just the script used to insert the post as that's the only place you need the API.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a PHP script on the Wordpress site that accepts a $_POST from the non-Wordpress site's form.

Wordpress site

/_static/receiver.php (I always put scripts like this in a folder named _static in the WP root folder):

```
<?php
require('../wp-load.php'); // Load Wordpress API
$data = ( isset( $_POST ) ) ? $_POST : null; // Get POST data, null on empty.
$post = array(
    'post_title'    => $data['post_title'],
    'post_content'  => $data['post_content'],
);
if ( $data && $data['key'] == '1234567890' ) // To Prevent Spam, bogus POSTs, etc.
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, true ); // Insert Post
?>
```

Non-Wordpress site form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://your-wordpress-site.com/_static/receiver.php">
    <input type="text" name="post_title" />
    <textarea name="post_content"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="1234567890" />
</form>
```