# I want to create posts for my Wordpress site, but where should I put the PHP file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use a PHP file to create posts for my Wordpress site by calling this kind of function:

```
wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
```

This PHP file reads some info from a database (not the Wordpress database), perform some data handling, and then call wp_xxxxxx() functions to write data into the Wordpress database.

I was originally thinking to put this PHP in a subdomain, but then I think it should be in somewhere related to the Wordpress because Wordpress functions/database are used.

Where is the best place I should put this file? Do I need to include anything in this PHP file? and then I can execute this PHP file via a web browser, like http://xxx.xxx.xxx/yyy1/yyy2/zzz.php?

And this PHP file can be called like a cron job every 15 mins?

Comment: can you give us a little more context? Are you just wanting to save a post that you have created in wordpress?

Comment: I want to use a PHP file to read data from a database (NOT the Wordpress database) and then write some data into the Wordpress database. And I hope this PHP file works like a cron job, so I can periodically read some data from a external database and then write some data into the Wordpress database (such as creating posts).

Comment: Ok, so in that context, you would need to create a PHP function that accesses the database. In the loop that you use to get your results, you should include your wp_insert_posts() call. I would suggest either putting it in the admin directory or in the template folder

Comment: better of as a plugin i reckon

Comment: If implementing it as a plugin, does it allow me to call this PHP directly via a web browser? Or I have to execute this PHP file inside Wordpress admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that best fits my conditions:

[Posting in wordpress database as a new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348666/posting-in-wordpress-database-as-a-new-post)

Just like the first answer, I add the PHP in http://MyWordPressdomain.com/scripts and in the PHP header I add

```
<?php 
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

I can now execute the PHP file from a web browser & from my site's cron job setting directly.